# Does ActiveModel::Serializer require an explicit render call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actioncontroller, active-model-serializers

I know that when using view templates (html, rabl), I don't need an explicit render call in my controller action because by default, Rails renders the template with the name corresponding to the controller action name. I like this concept (not caring about rendering in my controller code) and therefore wonder whether this is possible as well when using ActiveModel::Serializers?

Example, this is code from a generated controller (Rails 4.1.0):

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  #other actions
  # GET /products/1
  # GET /products/1.json
  def show
  end
end
```

and this is the serializer:

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :description, :url, :quantity, :price
end
```

Hitting /products/1.json, I would expect two things to happen:

1. Fields not listed in the serializer to be ommited,
2. Whole JSON object to be incapsulated within a 'product' top level field.

However, this does not happen, whole serializer is ignored. But then if I modify the Show method to the following:

```
# GET /products/1
# GET /products/1.json
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @product }
  end
end
```

And now it is all fine, but I have lost the benefit of the before_action filter (and it seems to me that I have some redundant code).

How should this really be done?

Comment: @zmilojko Have you tried using [`respond_with`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_with)? I think `respond_with(@product)` would get you close to if not exactly what you want. [Example from `ActiveModel::Serializer` README](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#render-json).

Comment: @PaulFioravanti But that is not what I am after. I would like `show` method to stay empty as Rails4 generator creates it, but to still be able to use Serializer as defined in the question (and not jbuilder, as it iseems Rails would prefer).

Comment: @zmilojko Is this a straight Rails 4.1 app? Or a rails-api app? How are you creating the initial state of your app?

Answer (score 0):

The 'redundant code' we see in the second one, is this line only:

`@product = Product.find(params[:id])`

And I believe this is the same logic as your before_action. You don't need this line, just remove it. Now the duplication is removed.

To the remaining part. An action needs to know what to render. By default if the action is empty or absent, the corresponding 'action_name'.html.erb (and other formats specified by `respond_to`) will be looked up and rendered.

This is why what the Rails 4 generator created works: it creates the `show.html.erb` and `show.json.jbuilder` which get rendered.

With `ActiveModel::Serializer`, you don't have a template. If you leave the action empty, it doesn't have a clue what to render. Thus you need to tell it to render the `@product` as json, by either:

`render json: @product`

or

`respond_with @product`

Comment: But my goal was not to remove the duplicate line, but the rest of it. I would like ´Show´ method to stay empty and still invoke the Serializer. That seems not to work, rendering the whole ActiveModel:Serializer useless.

Answer (score 0):

Without an explicit `render` or `respond_with` or `respond_to` Rails will look for a matching template. If that template does not exist Rails throws an error.

However, you can create your own resolver to bypass this. For instance, suppose you created `app\models\serialize_resolver.rb` and put this into it:

```
class SerializeResolver < ActionView::Resolver
  protected
  def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
    if details[:formats].to_a.include?(:json) && prefix !~ /layout/
      instance = prefix.to_s.singularize
      source = "<%= @#{instance}.active_model_serializer.new(@#{instance}).to_json.html_safe %>"
      identifier = "SerializeResolver - #{prefix} - #{name}"
      handler = ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
      details = {
        format: Mime[:json],
        updated_at: Date.today,
        virtual_path: "/#{normalize_path(name, prefix)}"
      }
      [ActionView::Template.new(source, identifier, handler, details)]
    else
      []
    end
  end

  def normalize_path(name, prefix)
    prefix.present? ? "#{prefix}/#{name}" : name
  end
end
```

And then, in either your application controller (or in an individual controller) place:

```
  append_view_path ::SerializeResolver.new
```

With that you should be able to do what you want. If it is a json request, it will create an erb template with the right content and return it.

Limitations:

- This is a bit clunky because it relies on erb, which is not needed. If I have time I will create a simple template handler. Then we can invoke that without erb.
- This does wipe out the default `json` response.
- It relies on the controller name to find the instance variable (`/posts` is converted to `@post`.)
- I've only tested this a little. The logic could probably be smarter.

Notes:

- If a template is present, it will be used first. That allows you to override this behavior.
- You can't simply create a new renderer and register it, because the default process doesn't hit it. If the template is not found, you get an error. If the file is found, it goes straight to invoking the template handler.

Comment: I repurposed some code from Jose Valim's book 'Crafting Rails' to create this answer.

Comment: Hmmm, I was looking for a solution to simplify my code, this is pretty much the opposite. I guess the jbuilder approach wins then, and ActiveModel:Serializer is just not so useful...

Comment: You could say that. But it only has to be done once.

Comment: I can't reproduce the question's generated output with Rails 4.1, rails-api, or active_model_serializers. Nor do I find any json examples without an explicit `render json:`. Are you using another gem? I only get an error without an explicit render. I might get you a better answer if I matched your setup.